# How to replace string in a array using sed in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a array declared in a file and i want to replace/update array with latest values.
below is the array saved in a file.

```
declare -A IMAGES_OVERRIDE
IMAGES_OVERRIDE=(
[service1]='gcr.io/test-project/image1:latest'
[service2]='gcr.io/test-project/image2:9.5.16'
[service3]='gcr.io/test-project/data/image3:latest'
)
```

Now I want to update service2 with latest image gcr.io/test-project/image2:10.0.1 and save into file.

I tried like below

```
sed -i 's/[service2]=.*/[service2]='gcr.io/test-project/image2:10.0.1'/' ./override
```

but I am getting below error.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unknown option to `s'
```

Same command is working me for other script but that is not array.

Comment: What research did you do on your own? And what exact errors do you have hard time with? (please add the info to your question) Note that we are not here to solve people's issues upon request. [How to ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```bash
> sed -i "s#\[service2\]=.*#[service2]='gcr.io/test-project/image2:10.0.1'#" ./override
```

- Notes:

1. Use <kbd>"</kbd> instead of <kbd>'</kbd> around `sed` expression (your `sed` script contains <kbd>'</kbd>);
2. Use <kbd>#</kbd> instead of <kbd>/</kbd> to limit each part of `sed` replace expression (your new token contains <kbd>/</kbd>);
3. Use <kbd>\</kbd> before each <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> in RE expression (<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> are special RE characters);